# function inside swith case - java programming

Tags: java, design-patterns, switch-statement, builder

Im learning java and i have come across a function calc (have changed few objects and removed few lines), however i couldnt understand below code...
I understand this follows builder pattern

Questions:

1. i have never seen this before and due to poor search i havent got much help from googling... can we do return new Object and a function below that...
   How this can be explained in simple terms
2. case 1 with no coding and default below that; does it mean 1 is most of the time default

Here is my code:

```
public calc(int value)
    {
        switch (value) {
        case 0:
            return new validator<objValidator>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean evaluate() {
                    //some business logic to return true/false
                    return true;
                }
            };

        case 1:
        default:
            return new validator<objValidator>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean evaluate() {
                    //some business logic to return true/false
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Err Not Builder... Factory...

Comment: Besides, you forgot the return type of the method....

Comment: That's not valid code. Either this is a constructor for a `calc` class (in which is shouldn't have return statements with values) or it's a method (in which case it doesn't have a return type). The lack of a declaration of `validator` doesn't help, nor does the fact that you're not following Java naming conventions. I see no indication that this is anything to do with the builder pattern, either.

Comment: retrun type is validator<objValidator>...my mistake.

Comment: Jon, i posted only the method having Anonymous inner class. I have tailored the code and thought this has enough details. I will correct it going forward.

Answer (score 2):

What you see here is called an anonymous inner class. Searching for that term should bring up some useful results.

Basically `validator<objValidator>` is an interface and you create an implementation of it in-place.

Comment: Thanks Henry, am able to call it with a name. anonymous inner class

Answer (score 0):

These are called as `Anonymous` Classes.
See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: yes you can

think about it like defining a new Anonymous class inside it

for more info about Anonymous classes

please see this link
[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Question 2:
case 1: means no action done if the value is 1
case default: means if the value not = 1 then the function below will be executed

for more info about switch case statement

[please point to this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)